# Passing extras between activities in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a string as an extra, but for some reason it just isn't going through. Here's my code:

```
public void setChordMajor(View v){
    chordType = "major";
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChordView.class);
    intent.putExtra("CHORD", chordType);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

CHORD is defined:

```
public final static String CHORD = "com.example.musiciansreference.EXTRA_CHORD";
```

And it is received by the next activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chord_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    chordType = intent.getStringExtra(Chords.CHORD);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(chordType);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Which just displays a blank screen. Somehow the string is not getting sent!

EDIT: I think the problem is in the second activity's ability to display the chord... here is the full code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChordView extends ActionBarActivity {



String chordType = "null";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chord_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    chordType = intent.getStringExtra(Chords.CHORD);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(chordType);

    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chord_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

intent.putExtra(Chords.CHORD, chordType); instead of intent.putExtra("CHORD", chordType);

Comment: Same problem still. I think the problem is with the latter activity being incapable of displaying text somehow, it seems if I set chordType there it still won't display...

Comment: This answer should fix your problem, but to explain the cause: When you start the activity, you are putting in the chord type with with the key "CHORD", but when you read it, you are reading the value stored at the key "com.example.musiciansreference.EXTRA_CHORD". Change either to the other, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way
Add a TextView element in the xml layout and from the ChordView in the Oncreate method reference it this way
TextView tv = (TextView) findviewbyId(R.id.tv);
Tv.setText(chordType); see if the  blank screen will still remain